# mod rewrite htaccess add dots on the pattern

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

just a quick question, how can I add dots (.) to my pattern? I dont want to use (*) all the symbols, just add the dot one.

For the moment I have this pat:

RewriteRule ^([a-z-_0-9]+)/([^/.]+)$

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `\.` to add the single dot to your pattern.